# Desktop Application to upload a txt file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, desktop-application, bucket

Well i been searching through the whole internet for something that solves my issue. I have read about the JSON API and Java Client for Cloud Storage but it seems this two apis required to be deployed on Compute engine and App Engine respectively. So i was wondering if there is a way to create a desktop application that sends a file to google Cloud storage bucket. Sorry im not an expert in this issue so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide), Google's "API Client Library for Java" is supported on vanilla Java (Java 5 and later).

> **Supported Java environments**
>
> The library supports the following Java environments:
>
> - Java 5 (or higher), standard (SE) and enterprise (EE)
> - Android 1.5 (or higher) (Note that this library's support for Android is @Beta.)
> - Google App Engine

You should be able to use that library as the starting point for your desktop application.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen C, this helped me to point me to the right direction. After reading the Developers Guide and seeing some examples of storage, I was able to get solution. If anyone needs help with this i would be more than happy to help them.